# Adjusting font size makes my container background image scale

Tags: css, background-image, font-size

I have a `<section>` with a background image and an `<h1>` inside of it, and whenever I adjust the `font-size` of the `<h1>`, the image scales to a certain point.

I've taken off block-level assignment of the `<h1>`, I've set absolute positioning, took off the `line-height`, and a number of other things. There was a point where the font was able to increase without effecting the background size of the `<section>`, but now I can't seem to adjust the `font-size` without effecting the background image.

**The Code:**

```css
.mis_banner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.mis_banner {
  background: url(../images/HeroDT.jpg) center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 94px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mis_banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-slide-bottom" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-bottom', repeat: false}">READY, <br> SET, <br> COOK!
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a natural result of setting the `background-size` to `scale`. When you make the text size larger, the container also needs to become larger to fit the text, and the background needs to become larger to cover the container.

If you don't want the background to scale, you can either remove `background-size`, or set it to a specific number like `50px auto`.